# multiplication shared preferences

Tags: android, mobile, multiplication

I wanted to calculate the variables inside sharedPreference. Some calculation might include multiplication and "if else". For example, if variable is more than 4 then multiply by 10, if more than 7 multiply by 11.

Anyone can show an example of how to do this?

Money is the one involving multiplication. the error says operator "*" cannot be applied to android.widget.EditText. How to fix this?

```
package com.example.shyan.prototype;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class user_input2 extends Activity {

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPreferenceFile";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.user_input2);

    final EditText item = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextpower);
    final EditText price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextusage);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonsave);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("item", item.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("price", price.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("money", item*price);
            editor.commit();


            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Report.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your issue is you cant multiple editTexts like that, if you want there numeric value then do this:

```
final EditText item_et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextpower);
    final EditText price_et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextusage);

    int item=Integer.parseInt(item.getText().toString());
    int price = Integer.parseInt(price.getText().toString());
```

now you can do item*price and save it as a int  like this:

```
editor.puInt("money",item*price)
```

Comment: but now it says variable "price" might not have been initialized

Comment: i changed it to price_et n the error is gone. Thanks.
if i have many buttons then should i add thing properties n the whole coding into each and every one?

Comment: i dont understand what your asking. its not clear what you want to do ? fix your typos

Comment: sorry. I mean I have many different buttons that is used for different product (item is the quantity). When i clicked on a product button this will come out. 
(i) Do i need to create different activities for different product or there is another way to do it? 
(ii) How can i display a different text view according to the name product if that specific product button has been clicked?

Comment: you should be able to do it on one screen.  you know you can in xml hide views and then show them from code right ? look up visiblity:gone   in android xml. I hope i was able to answer your original question. I dont know anything more on what your asking.